# Angular state transition is suspending timeout

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an Angular app and I am using active state (color change) on a button using Javascript and timeout. Something like this in my service:

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-numeric" ng-mousedown="highlightButtonThenAddValue(4, $event)">4</div>
```

Controller Code:

```
var abc = [];

var highlightButtonTouch = function (event, addClassName) {
   var element = event.currentTarget;
   var currClasses = element.classList.add(addClassName);
   setTimeout(function () {
   element.classList.remove(addClassName);
   }, 100);


$scope.highlightButtonThenAddValue = function (value, event) {
    log.debug("button pressed on screen, button value: " + value);
    highlightButtonTouch(event, 'btn-numeric-active');
    $scope.add_value(value);
};

$scope.add_value(value) {
    abc.push(value);
    if (abc.length === 6) {
       $state.go(newState);
    }
}
```

This works fine if the button color change is on the same state. However, when enough values are added, I need to change the state using state.go and in that case, class 'btn-numeric-active' is not removed even after 100ms, instead the css change to add btn-numeric-active stays until state changes. I have a few resolves defined on the new state - in which I am making API calls to server.

You can see this issue only on reducing CPU to 10Xslowdown in Chrome performance tab. But my application is supposed to run on slow machines.

Has anyone faced similar issue ? Any suggestions on how to fix this ?

Things I have tried:

I can't use :active pseudo class, as that enables active state even on touch and drag while click is not registered.

I have tried defining the element as a rootScope variable, but that also doesn't solve the problem.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: can you try using `$timeout` instead of `setTimeout`?

Comment: @lcycool Tried. No change in the behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I know what the issue is, its because of the way javascript works.

The timeout callback is added in call stack. During state change, I have a few 'resolves' in which I am making API call, those are adding callbacks in the call stack too, and it being a stack, the callbacks for resolves are being processed before the callback for timeout.

Thus, the line `element.classList.remove(addClassName);`  is being executed after all API calls for state transition finishes. I had to make the following changes to my code, for things to work:

```
var highlightButtonTouch = function (event, addClassName) {
   var deferred = $q.defer();
   var element = event.currentTarget;
   var currClasses = element.classList.add(addClassName);
   setTimeout(function () {
     element.classList.remove(addClassName);
     deferred.resolve();
   }, 100);
   return deferred.promise;
}
```

And in controller:

```
$scope.highlightButtonThenAddValue = function (value, event) {
    log.debug("button pressed on screen, button value: " + value);
    highlightButtonTouch(event, 'btn-numeric-active').then(function() {
        $scope.add_value(value);
    });
};
```

This resolved the issue.

Silly me, I should keep reminding myself of the basic javascript behaviour - event loop and call stack.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try wrapping it in a directive?

```js
angular.module('test', [])
.controller('TestController', TestController)
.directive('fancyButton', fancyButtonDirective);

function TestController() {}

function fancyButtonDirective() {
  return {
    scope: { name: '@' },
    template: '<button type="button" ng-mouseover="highLight()">{{name}}</button>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.highLight = function() {
        var button = element.find('button')[0];
        button.classList.add('light');
        setTimeout(function() { button.classList.remove('light'); }, 200);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.light {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='test' ng-controller='TestController'>
  <fancy-button name="Fancy 1"></fancy-button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But I found out that the problem was different - it was related to javascript call stack and timeout callback being executed after API callbacks. Please find my answer below.